# Autocomplete box error

Tags: c#, xml, autocomplete, windows-phone, autocompletebox

I have a xml file and I want to search in it with an autocomplete box.
I use code below but the it crashed. How can I fix it or is there a way better?

```
               XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("BankCode.xml");

        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("BankCode")
                   select new BankData
                   {
                       BankName= (string)query.Element("Bank"),
                   };
        this.acBox.ItemsSource = data;

        XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("BankCode.xml");
        var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("Bank")
                           where c.Attribute("Code").Value == acBox.Text
                           select new BankData()
                           {
                               Code= c.Attribute("Code").Value
                           };
        listBox1.ItemsSource = filteredData;
```

I want to create an app that when the user type the bank name in autocomplete box after pressing the search button the bank code has shown to him/her. (!!The acBox is an autocomplete box.)

Comment: Please explain 'crashed'. Is there an exception thrown? Also, you will need to show some markup from 'BankCode.xml'...

Comment: When I use a bank from autocomplete box and press the search button it crashed and the debugger shows this code as error: 'where c.Attribute("Code").Value == acBox.Text'  and says _An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DatabindingAutoCompleteBox.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object._

Comment: try to add a null check ? `where c.Attribute("Code") != null && c.Attribute("Code").Value == acBox.Text`. NRE seems to mean that  `c.Attribute("Code")` is null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems 1 of your `Bank` nodes does not have a `Code` attribute. 
You should add a NULL check:

```
var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("Bank")
                   where c.Attribute("Code") != null && c.Attribute("Code").Value == acBox.Text
                   select new BankData()
                   {
                       Code= c.Attribute("Code").Value
                   };
```